# Bundling constraints with fundeps

Tags: haskell, ghc, functional-dependencies, type-constraints

I've got a function `foo` with a litany of constraints. Of course these constraints must appear in the signatures of functions that use `foo`, so what I'm trying to do is wrap the `foo` constraints in a type synonym `FooCtx a b ... :: Constraint`. As an example,

```
foo :: (A a, B b, C c, ...) => a -> b -> c

bar :: (A a, B b, C c, ...) ...
bar = ... foo ...
```

would become

```
type FooCtx a b c ... = (A a, B b, C c, ...)
foo :: (FooCtx a b c) => a -> b -> c
bar :: (FooCtx a b c) => ...
```

This works great if all of the types are exposed. However, I'm using functional dependencies to generate some of the types in the constraint list, and those types don't appear in the signature of `foo`. For example:

```
class Bar a b | a -> b

foo (Bar a b, ...) => a -> a
```

GHC won't accept `type FooCtx a = (Bar a b)` because `b` isn't bound on the LHS. Neither can I use `type FooCtx a b = (Bar a b)` because `b` isn't in scope in the signature of `foo`. The signature of `foo` would be `foo :: (FooCtx a ?) => a -> a`.

One unsatisfactory solution is to put one of the constraints in the `foo` signature with `FooCtx` to bring the fundep type in to scope:

```
class Bar a b | a -> b

type FooCtx a b = ...

foo (Bar a b, FooCtx a b) => a -> a
```

but this defeats the purpose of grouping the constraints:

Until encountering this case, I assumed that Constraint synonyms could be blindly substituted for arbitrary constraint lists. The only other way I know to encapsulate constraints like this is with a class, but it suffers from the same problem: `class (A a, B b, C c, ...) => FooCtx a b c` can't have any hidden types on the LHS. Is there some other way I might be able to fully gather all of these constraints?

Comment: What's wrong with `type FooCtx a b = ...` - this is only 2 characters longer than `type FooCtx a = ...`.

Comment: As I mentioned above, GHC accepts your signature, but it is useless to me on the LHS of `foo` because `b` is not in scope in the signature of `foo`.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use `TypeFamilies` instead of `FunctionalDependencies`?

Comment: @Cirdec Now that you mention it, is there ever a reason? Aren't they isomorphic? That would allow me to bring those new types in scope...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how type variables are bound. They are **not** bound by the tau type (the `a -> a` in your example), but an implicit binder based on the full phi type (`(Bar a b) => a -> a`). This binding can be made explicit with the `ExplicitForAll` GHC language extension.

In your example, when you write  something like

```
foo :: (Bar a b) => a -> a
```

then the full sigma type, with explicit tyvar-binding spelled out, is the following (since in the implicit case, all tyvars from the phi type are bound here)

```
foo :: forall a b. (Bar a b) => a -> a
```

This means there is no problem in using a constraint alias the same way: if you have e.g.

```
type FooCtx a b = (Bar a b, Num a, Eq a)
```

then the following is a valid type signature:

```
foo' :: forall a b. (FooCtx a b) => a -> a
```

and thus, the following shorthand is valid as well:

```
foo' :: (FooCtx a b) => a -> a
```

Comment: How interesting! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved with `TypeFamilies` and `FlexibleContexts`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
```

We have three classes, `A`, `B`, and `C` and your original `foo` function.

```
class A a
class B a
class C a

foo :: (A a, B b, C c) => a -> b -> c
foo = undefined
```

The `Bar` class uses a type family to figure out what `B` goes with an `a`. I've added an additional function to it just to write the example `foo'`.

```
class Bar a where
    type BofA a :: *
    aToB :: a -> BofA a
```

`foo'` is a function that doesn't have any inputs or outputs that are `B`, but still uses `foo` in its implementation. It requires that the `BofA` type associated with `a` satisfy the `B` constraint. This signature requires flexible contexts.

```
foo' :: (A a, Bar a, B (BofA a), C c) => a -> a -> c
foo' x y = foo x (aToB y)
```